# unable to properly install pygobjects

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygtk, pygobject

After a frustrating two weeks I am still unable to install pygobjects. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling but with no success. I have thoroughly researched the issue and I don't have an answer of why it won't work. I am currently running on a windows 7 64-bit machine. I currently have installed python 2.7, GTK+ 3.6.4, pygi 3.14, and I am using pycharm as my IDE. Whenever I try to import Gtk using:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
```

I get an error about an "unresolved reference". Upon investigation I find that my gi.repository is empty other than the __int__.py. What did I do wrong?